# Python 2 vs Python 3 - Difference in behavior of filter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone please help me understand why the following code that implements the "sieve of Eratosthenes" behaves differently across Python 2 and Python 3.

```
l = range(2, 20)
for i in range(2, 6):
    l = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i != 0, l)
print(tuple(l))
```

With Python 2.7:

```
> python filter.py
(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)
```

with Python 3.6:

```
> python filter.py
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19)
```

I understand that Python3's filter returns a filter object but can't explain the final result. (The code is from this lambdas tutorial [1](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)).

Comment: Because in Python-3.x, `filter behaves as a generator.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you should write a full answer. This kind of question deserves it.

Comment: @Soviut: I'm working on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two parts that play a role here:

- in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), `filter` works as a generator: the filtering is done lazy; and
- the `i` in the `lambda x : ...` is updated as well as the `i` in the `for` loop makes progression.

So at the end what you have constructed is something like:

```
l = filter(lambda x: x == 5 or x % 5 != 0,
        filter(lambda x: x == 5 or x % 5 != 0,
            filter(lambda x: x == 5 or x % 5 != 0,
                filter(lambda x: x == 5 or x % 5 != 0,l)
            )
        )
    )
```

Note that **all filtering is done as if `i` was `5` all the time**. So now you call `tuple(..)`, the actual filtering will be done, and as you can see only multiples of five that are not five themeselves are filtered out.

An easy fix is to use `list` in the loop such that the `filter`ing is done actively:

```
l = range(2, 20)
for i in range(2, 6):
    l = list(filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i != 0, l))
print(tuple(l))
```

Running this in python returns:

```
>>> l = range(2, 20)
>>> for i in range(2, 6):
...     l = list(filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i != 0, l))
... 
>>> print(l)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Mind that although [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) look quite the same these are actually "different" languages that are incompatible with each other: running code written in one will not always work in the other and vice versa.

Another note (credits to @ShadowRanger) is that one actually **can bind `i`** in your lambda. You do this by creating a "higher order lambda". Instead of writing:

```
lambda x : x == i or x % i != 0
```

you write:

```
(lambda j : (lambda x : x == j or x % j != 0))(i)
```

What happens is you define a function that takes as input a `j` that actually takes the value of `i`. By calling it immediately, `j` binds to the value of `i`.

Comment: Note that you could get the same results without intermediate lists by binding the value of `i` in the `lambda` so it isn't updated on each loop: `filter(lambda x, i=i: x == i or x % i != 0, l)` Setting a default parameter of `i=i` binds at definition time so it isn't modified by the progression of the loop.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: that is indeed a good point. I will edit my answer to include this.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I defined a higher order function, since it is more clear what happens. Nevertheless your approach works as well. It all has to do with defining a local `i`.

Answer (score 9):

In Python-3 `filter` returns a generator (in Python-2 it returns a list), so it's evaluated when you consume it. But that wouldn't be a problem by itself, the problem is that your `i` changes. At the time you consume the `filter` your `i = 5` and all your `filter` just check for that.

I include some `print`-statements so you can more easily follow what is happening:

```
l = range(2, 20)
for i in range(2, 6):
    l = filter(lambda x: print(x, i) or (x == i or x % i != 0), l)
list(l)

2 5
2 5
2 5
2 5
3 5
3 5
3 5
3 5
4 5
4 5
4 5
4 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
5 5
6 5
6 5
6 5
6 5
7 5
7 5
7 5
7 5
8 5
8 5
8 5
8 5
9 5
9 5
9 5
9 5
10 5
11 5
11 5
11 5
11 5
12 5
12 5
12 5
12 5
13 5
13 5
13 5
13 5
14 5
14 5
14 5
14 5
15 5
16 5
16 5
16 5
16 5
17 5
17 5
17 5
17 5
18 5
18 5
18 5
18 5
19 5
19 5
19 5
19 5

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

That probably wasn't your intention. You could bind `i` to your lambda:

```
l = range(2, 20)
for i in range(2, 6):
    l = filter((lambda j: lambda x: print(x, j) or (x == j or x % j != 0))(i), l)
    # or
    # l = filter(lambda x, i=i: print(x, i) or (x == i or x % i != 0), l)
list(l)
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
4 2
5 2
5 3
5 4
5 5
6 2
7 2
7 3
7 4
7 5
8 2
9 2
9 3
10 2
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
12 2
13 2
13 3
13 4
13 5
14 2
15 2
15 3
16 2
17 2
17 3
17 4
17 5
18 2
19 2
19 3
19 4
19 5

[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

or cast your `filter`-result immediatly to a `tuple`:

```
l = range(2, 20)
for i in range(2, 6):
    l = tuple(filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i != 0, l))
print(l)
# (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)
```