# Reading cookie values in Python 3

Tags: python

I have this Python 2 code :

```
import requests
import json
import Cookie

USERNAME = "<user_name>"
PASSWORD = "<password>"
BACKEND = "https://blahblah.com"

# login will take orgId, email and password and return auth cookie for the user
def login(email, password):
    url = 'https://auth-v2.blahblah.com/auth/v1.0/login'
    data = json.dumps({'email':email, 'password': password})
    r = requests.post(url,data=data,allow_redirects=False)
    cookieHeaders = filter(lambda x: x.lower()=='set-cookie',r.headers.keys())
    if len(cookieHeaders)==0:
        return None
    bc = Cookie.BaseCookie(r.headers[cookieHeaders[0]])
    sess = 'sess='+bc.values()[0].value
    return sess
```

But I can't translate it properly into Python 3.

I just need the Set-Cookie value from the headers, but either the filter function or lambda isn't working the same as in Python 2.

It looks like the filter() function in Python 2 returns a filter object which then fails the len() check and the "bc = " line as well.

How can I access the cookie values properly ?

Comment: I would change the title of the question: this is not about cookies but about differences between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: You need to actually perform the filtering :  `len(list(filter(...)))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2 vs Python 3 - Difference in behavior of filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666977/python-2-vs-python-3-difference-in-behavior-of-filter)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Requests module and the requests.Session object
[Quick Start](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content); [Sessions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

[Refer this stackoverflow question for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606083/how-to-set-and-retrieve-cookie-in-http-header-in-python)

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')
print(r.text)
# '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}}'

print(s.cookies)
# RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='sessioncookie', value='123456789', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='httpbin.org', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is slightly different in Python 2 than in Python3.

In Python 2 the following works just fine:

```
foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
len(filter(lambda x: x>2, foo))
```

This works because `type(filter(lambda x: x>2, foo))` is `list`.

While in Python 3 you need a `list` constructor:

```
foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
len(list(filter(lambda x: x>2, foo)))
```

Indeed in Python 3 `type(filter(lambda x: x>2, foo))` is `<class 'filter'>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try build-in cookie feature:

```
import requests

def login(email, password):
    url = 'https://wordpress.com/'
    data = {'email': email, 'password': password}
    r = requests.post(url, json=data, allow_redirects=False)

    print(r.cookies)
    print(r.cookies.get_dict())
    print(r.cookies.get_dict(domain='wordpress.com'))

    sess = 'sess={}'.format(r.cookies.get_dict()['wp_locale_test_group'])
    print(sess)
    return sess
```

will produce:

```
print(r.cookies)
```

→

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie SSE_blogger_ecommerce_20181217=test-a for .wordpress.com/>, <Cookie tk_ai=ZCGvpAX2VOVR5RO11DPzA1dm for .wordpress.com/>, <Cookie wp_locale_test_group=jan-2019 for wordpress.com/>]>
```

═══

```
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
```

→

```
{'SSE_blogger_ecommerce_20181217': 'test-a', 'tk_ai': 'ZCGvpAX2VOVR5RO11DPzA1dm', 'wp_locale_test_group': 'jan-2019'}
```

═══

```
print(r.cookies.get_dict(domain='wordpress.com'))
```

→

```
{'wp_locale_test_group': 'jan-2019'}
```

═══

```
print(sess)
```

→

```
sess=jan-2019
```